# Why Python run only first method of reading file?

Tags: python, text-files, readfile

I was trying reading file methods and Python only run method which i wrote first. Im beginner. What is the reason for this?

First Example:

```
fhandle = open('TestTXT.txt')

for line in fhandle:
    print(line)

print (fhandle.read())
```

[image: First Example Result]

Second Example:

```
fhandle = open('TestTXT.txt')

print (fhandle.read())

for line in fhandle:
    print(line)
```

[image: Second Example Result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file object stores the current offset, which moves forward as you read. Once you read till the end, you need to either re-open the file, or move the offset to the beginning, using `seek`:

```
print(fhandle.read())  
fhandle.seek(0)
for line in fhandle:  
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, each line of the file is being printed, but with an extra line feed from the `print()` function:

```py
fhandle = open('TestTXT.txt')

for line in fhandle:
    print(line)   # extra line feed for each line

print(fhandle.read())   # Does nothing!
```

In the second example you are printing the contents of the file in one go, plus one extra line feed from the `print()` function:

```py
fhandle = open('TestTXT.txt')

print(fhandle.read())  # everything printed here

for line in fhandle:   # does nothing
    print(line)
```